# What is the effect of treating the samples of a non stationary process as stationary and plotting their distribution

Tags: distributions, stationarity, histogram

Say I have a non stationary process. Let's say I take one realization of this process given by finite number of random variables $X_1$, $X_2$,...$X_n$. Now I plot them on a histogram. Can this histogram (distribution) change significantly with multiple realizations of the same non stationary process?

Comment: Could you clarify for us what you mean by "samples"?  Are each of the $X_i$ independent realizations of this *process* or are they random variables?  If it's the latter, what you seem to be saying is that you have a finite collection of random variables but otherwise impose no conditions on them, which makes it difficult to conclude much.

Comment: I meant random variables. Edited the question. I understand that there is not much that can be concluded with the little information. An alternative question that can be asked is are their examples of non-stationary processes where the histogram has meaningful information. One simplifying case could be if all the samples are independent and have gaussian distribution with the same variance but mean varying with time t as sin(t).

Comment: Hi @whuber. I have changed the question to make it much more concrete now.

Comment: The histogram corresponds to a distribution which is a mixture of (possibly many) distributions as far as the observation design remains fixed. So if you consider two sets of many (independent) realizations the distributions should be nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

Stationary or nonstationary, a histogram can vary a lot across realizations of a process. You could see this by simulating realizations of an i.i.d. process and drawing their histograms:

```r
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(i in 1:9){
  set.seed(i+12345)
  x=runif(20)
  hist(x,breaks=seq(from=0,to=1,by=0.2))
}; par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

For an ergodic process, this variation should subside as the sample size increases, as the law of large numbers starts kicking in.  in the R script, substitute the sample size of 20 by 10000 to obtain this:

[image]

Without ergodicity, this need not happen. And for a stochastic process $\{X_t\}$, absence of stationarity implies absence of ergodicity. Absence of ergodicity means that the sample mean of a finite piece of the $i$th realization of the process, $(x_{1,i},\dots,x_{T,i})$, does not necessarily converge (as $T\rightarrow\infty$) to $\mathbb{E}(X)$. This also means that the histogram (with bar lengths divided by the number of data points it is based on) of $(x_{1,i},\dots,x_{T_i})$ will not necessarily approach the density of $X$. If we consider a pair of realizations $(i,j)$, we do not see a reason why their histograms should converge to a common target and thus also approach each other as $T\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Your conclusion does not follow from your argument.  Indeed, even in a stationary process the histogram of a realization will vary among realizations.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. I need to be more careful with the phrasing; it came out wrong. I will edit once I get a moment.

Comment: @whuber, I have edited my answer now.

Comment: That's good, thanks.  But it seems to me that histograms can also stabilize in some non-ergodic processes, indicating that the underlying concept isn't ergodicity but something else.  Moreover, with a finite but sufficiently long time sequence, repeated realizations of a non-stationary process (with finite marginal variances) very well could be quite stable, again suggesting ergodicity is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @whuber, I suppose ergodicity is a sufficient condition but not a necessary one. Or do you believe otherwise?

Comment: Because ergodicity concerns what happens in the limit as the times increase but this question concerns what happens when multiple realizations are examined for a fixed finite prefix of times, it is difficult to see how ergodicity would be relevant.

Comment: @whuber, so then the first two sentences of my answer + the R simulation is all that is needed? Or should something more be added? I realize that what happens in the limit is not what the OP is interest in, but I was tempted to provide this analysis in addition to the two sentences at the start (which I had omitted in my original answer).

Comment: I was also interested in what happens at the limit. I understand that for small sequence lengths even for stationary processes the histogram can change a lot across multiple realizations. The interesting bit is if non stationary processes can have stable histogram of realizations, and what is the condition for which this should hold.

Comment: @AkshatJoshi, I think they can. Take a process that consists of independent random variables where the odd ones have one distribution and the even ones another. As the sample size increases, you will get closer and closer to a 50%/50% mixture of the two distributions.

Comment: @RichardHardy Isn't that a stationary process though, as the joint distribution of (Xt, Xt+1) will remain the same across time t?

Comment: @AkshatJoshi, no, because not only the joint distribution will not remain the same as $(X,Y)$ is not the same as $(Y,X)$ but also because $X$ and $Y$ have two different marginal distributions, and that is not permitted under stationarity.

Comment: Oh that's right. I made a mistake there. For stationarity the marginal and the joint distribution of any number of random variables must have the same distribution across time.